# Delete button is disabled due to time out issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, javascript-remoting

I have a page where websites are built by the users. When an user tries to delete the site from the page, the page is throwing error stating there is some issue and the delete button is disabled immediately. It is re-enabled when refreshed. 
When I verified the code, there is some function written to disable the delete button and it is as follows:

```
 function reallyDeleteWebsite(){ 
        $('#reallyDeleteBtn').attr('disabled','disabled');

        Visualforce.remoting.timeout = 120000;
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.Account_AccWebsiteBuilderCntl.deleteWebsite}',
            websiteToDelete,            
            function(result, event){ 
                if (event.status) {                 
                    var resp = JSON.parse(result);  

                    if (resp.status == 'success'){
                        // Reload page                      
                        location.reload();                      
                    } else {                    
                        $('#errDeleteMsg').show();          
                    }
                } 
            }, 
            {escape: false, buffer:false}
        );  
    }
```

Can anyone help me solving this error.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The disabling of the delete button just seems to be a UI/UX state handling thing where the developer of this code wanted to prevent multiple clicks of the delete website button.

I guess if an error occurs, and you want to permit the user to click on the delete website button again without any further checking, or interaction, you could simply unset the disabled attribute in the error handling block of your callback.

```
    $('#reallyDeleteBtn').prop('disabled', true );

    ...

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.Account_AccWebsiteBuilderCntl.deleteWebsite}',
        websiteToDelete,            
        function(result, event){ 
            if (event.status) {                 
                var resp = JSON.parse(result);  

                if (resp.status == 'success'){
                    // Reload page                      
                    location.reload();                      
                } else {                    
                    $('#errDeleteMsg').show();    
                    $('#reallyDeleteBtn').prop('disabled', false );      
                }
            } 
        }, 
        {escape: false, buffer:false}
    );
```

I'd want to really test this before rolling it into production. Why did they build it this way? Was there a reason to not permit a user to click on it again when in an error state?

Also note, I'm not a jQuery expert, but reading the current API [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2), and perusing this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery), accessing something like `disabled` is not considered an attribute, rather as a property.

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value.

So the correct API to use for manipulating property values is `element.prop('propname', value)`. As such, I've used it for both the call to re-enable the button, but also corrected the initial call to disable it.

An alternative would be to add a click event handler on the error message element itself. (Maybe there is one already?) In this instance, you could call the line of code to re-enable the delete button upon the user dismissing the error message, ensuring they have acknowledged and interacted with it (should some user intervention be required).

Comment: Thank you for the reply
My requirement is to delete the link when delete button is clicked. But I do not know what reason, it is throwing an error stating that "There is some issue deleting the site". And immediately, the delete button is disabled. It is re-enabled once page is refreshed. Can you please let me know why this happens when a button is clicked

Comment: So the problem isn't that the button is disabled, it is that there is an error at all? I think you'd need to understand the implementation of the Account_AccWebsiteBuilderCntl.deleteWebsite method in Apex. But this is more of a debugging problem, which isn't well suited for a StackExchange question. Still, if you can post the code from Apex, and as much detail of the error message, there may be something to answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the problem statement, If you want to enable the delete button by the following code if the code throws an error.

---

```
 function reallyDeleteWebsite(){ 
    $('#reallyDeleteBtn').attr('disabled','disabled');

    Visualforce.remoting.timeout = 120000;
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.Account_AccWebsiteBuilderCntl.deleteWebsite}',
        websiteToDelete,            
        function(result, event){ 
            if (event.status) {                 
                var resp = JSON.parse(result);  

                if (resp.status == 'success'){
                    // Reload page                      
                    location.reload();                      
                } else {                    
                    $('#errDeleteMsg').show(); 
                    //++ here you can enable the delete button
                    $('#reallyDeleteBtn').removeAttribute('disabled');         
                }
            } 
        }, 
        {escape: false, buffer:false}
    );  
}
```

Let me know If this tweak helps...